# Bluetooth - Class 1 Devices?

Tags: android, mobile, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am looking at supplementing a WiFi solution with a Bluetooth connection that will eventually communicate to a device via RS485.

This solution will need to be able to be a decent distance apart from one another.  While looking into Bluetooth Class 1, I can't seem to find much information about devices that support this power rating.

Are there any consumer phones and/or tablets (preferably Android) that are Bluetooth Class 1?  Does anyone have feedback on Bluetooth Class 1 performance vs a standard 802.11b/g/n WiFi network?

Any insight is appreciated.